# Bit masking 32bit integer resulting negative value in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to check whether the 2most left bit exists in nodejs, but I get a negative number instead, can you help me what's going on in here? I tried the same thing in cpp, php, and ruby and it works fine

```js
const pixel = 0xFF0F7700
const red = 0xFF000000

console.log("Bit Pixel: ", pixel.toString(2))
console.log("Bit Red:   ", red.toString(2))
console.log("Pixel & Red", ((pixel&red)).toString(2)) // The output is -1000000000000000000000000 , not even 32 bit length
```

The similar code in ruby,

```
puts (0xFF0F7700 & 0xFF000000).to_s(2) # the result is 11111111000000000000000000000000
```

Thank you :)

Comment: JavaScript Uses 32 bits Bitwise Operands: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp

Comment: You could use `(pixel>>>24).toString(2)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 sure that would do the trick but I just why this happen

Comment: @root oh, are you proposing this happens because integer overflow in 32 bit?

Comment: You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers.  Basically, bitwise operators except shifting don't work the way you expect if the highest bit is on because JS turns them into a 32-bit two's complement before applying the operator.  Why they do that, I don't know?  That's why I offered the shift solution which doesn't have that issue.

Comment: Cool, thanks @jfriend00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers.

Basically, bitwise operators except shifting don't work the way you expect if the highest 32-bit bit is on because before applying the bitwise operator, JS turns them into a 32-bit two's complement before applying the operator. Why they do that, I have no idea, but it's the way it works?

So, it's better to use bit shifting which doesn't have that weird behavior and offers bit shift operators that do or don't preserve the sign bit depending upon whether you want to be working with a signed or unsigned value.

So, for your operation, you could do:

```js
const pixel = 0xFF0F7700
const red = 0xFF000000

console.log("Bit Pixel: ", pixel.toString(2))
console.log("Bit Red:   ", red.toString(2))
console.log("Pixel & Red", (pixel >>> 24).toString(2))
```

And, get the result you wanted that way.  You could even put them back into the original bit positions like this:

```js
const pixel = 0xFF0F7700
const red = 0xFF000000

console.log("Bit Pixel: ", pixel.toString(2))
console.log("Bit Red:   ", red.toString(2))
console.log("Pixel & Red", (pixel >>> 24).toString(2))
console.log("Pixel & Red", ((pixel >>> 24) * 256 * 256 * 256).toString(2))
```

Honestly, I have no idea in these days of 64-bit processors why this is this broken.  I guess bit manipulation in Javascript just isn't a priority.

Comment: JS is a broken in many respects, just try `parseInt('20oiglergjergj')`

Comment: @root - On that one, garbage in, garbage out.  Yep, `parseInt()` has pretty much always been bonkers.  At least they've finally standardized on `0x, 0o, 0b` for literal definitions and the legacy stuff was even booted out of strict mode, but the legacy stuff remains in `parseInt()`.

Comment: @thatbuffdude - Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sure, although I'm not satisfied with the answer, at least I know what's going on here, thanks

Comment: @root It's not broken, it's a feature :D